# How to solve this return type function error in Rust

Tags: rust, return, future

I am creating a rust web application. I am new to this thing and I am trying to make API requests and pass a result form a request as Response to the web view. There are main.rs , route.rs and common.rs files. Basically main.rs file call relevant route and then route will call the function.

But, there is an error with a function in the route.rs file.

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `fn() -> impl std::future::Future {<search::routes::get_token as actix_web::service::HttpServiceFactory>::register::get_token}: actix_web::handler::Factory<_, _, _>` is not satisfied
  --> src\search\routes.rs:20:10
   |
20 | async fn get_token() -> Result<String, reqwest::Error> {
   |          ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `actix_web::handler::Factory<_, _, _>` is not implemented for `fn() -> impl std::future::Future {<search::routes::get_token as actix_web::service::HttpServiceFactory>::register::get_token}`
```

How can I Fix this ??

route.rs

```
use crate::search::User;
use actix_web::{get, post, put, delete, web, HttpResponse, Responder};
use serde_json::json;
extern crate reqwest;
extern crate serde;
mod bfm;
mod common;

#[get("/token")]
async fn get_token() -> Result<String, reqwest::Error> {

    let set_token = common::authenticate(); 
    // let set_token = common::get_rust_posts();
    return set_token.await;
    //HttpResponse::Ok().json(set_token)
}
```

common.rs

```
extern crate reqwest;
use reqwest::header::HeaderMap;
use reqwest::header::AUTHORIZATION;
use reqwest::header::CONTENT_TYPE;

pub async fn authenticate() -> Result<String, reqwest::Error> {

    fn construct_headers() -> HeaderMap {
        let mut headers = HeaderMap::new();

        headers.insert(AUTHORIZATION, "Basic bghythjuikyt==".parse().unwrap());
        headers.insert(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".parse().unwrap());

        assert!(headers.contains_key(AUTHORIZATION));
        assert!(!headers.contains_key(CONTENT_TYPE));

        headers
    }

    let client = reqwest::Client::new();

    let reszr = client.post("https://api.test.com/auth/token")
    .headers(construct_headers())
    .body("grant_type=client_credentials")
        .send()
        .await?
        .text()
        .await;

        return reszr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please read: https://actix.rs/docs/errors/

--

Do you have implemented `ResponseError` for `reqwest::Error`?

You have to implement `ResponseError` trait because framework have to response with something in case when `Result` is `Err`.

Here is an example

```rust
impl ResponseError for Error {
    fn error_response(&self) -> HttpResponse {
        match self.kind_ref() {
            ErrorKind::HttpResponse { msg, code, real } => {
                println!("{}", real);

                HttpResponse::build(code.to_owned()).json(json!({
                    "status": false,
                    "msg": msg
                }))
            }
            _ => {
                println!("{}", self);

                HttpResponse::build(StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).finish()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Error` in this case is my custom error that contains `msg`, `code`, `real`, but the logic should be similar in your case.

--

UPDATE: after @Masklinn comment about `error[E0117]: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for arbitrary types`

Code above works only on custom `Error` you own.

What you can to do is:

- map `reqwest::Error` to `Error` that already implements `ResponseError`. You can check list of implementations here: https://docs.rs/actix-web/3.0.0-alpha.1/actix_web/trait.ResponseError.html#implementors
- create custom `Error` that wraps `reqwest::Error` (and other errors in your code) and implement `ResponseError` on it (this is basicaly same/similar as first)

Comment: Since they're the author of neither the trait (would be actix) nor the struct (would be reqwuest) they'll probably have to bounce the error through a type of their own, at the very least a newtype of reqwest::Error.